# How to reference the official oracle documentation?

Tags: reference-request

I would like to reference some material from the official Oracle documentation for my bachelor thesis. The piece of documentation I want to include is giving information about [data types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330). The problem I have is that I didn't find any information about the author, address, year, etc.

How do I reference that then? Or does anybody of you found some information about a specific author, year, etc. ?

Comment: Because that's webpage, I would do something like this: http://www.easybib.com/reference/guide/apa/website or if you think it is more of a technical manual, something like this https://penandthepad.com/do-cite-technical-manual-apa-6867383.html

Answer (score 1):

Abstract concepts such as `datetime` or `longs` are generally not attributed to Oracle or similar companies, if anything you should cite an earlier work that discusses and introduces the concepts. The earliest mention that I know that introduces most of these concepts that are used in many (if not all) modern databases and programming languages derive from `C`, it even introduced us to the `Hello World` concept. Therefore a good reference would be:

> Kernighan, B. W., & Ritchie, D. M. (1978). The C programming language.
>   Prentice-Hall, Inc. Upper Saddle River, NJ, USA (ISBN: 0-13-110163-3).

Co-incidentally, according to Google Scholar this work has been referenced 8000+ times as of the 4th of December, 2018.

PS: There may be earlier references of specific datatypes, but I argue that no other work has brought them all together in one place before the work of Kernighan and Ritchie.